# BokehJS library is missing while running the webpage on an apache2 server

Tags: apache, bokeh

I'm trying to show a webpage rendered by bokeh on an apache2 server, so I've followed the [documentation](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#apache) and this is my .conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName MyWebpageAdress.se

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /ws ws://127.0.0.1:5100/webpage/ws
    ProxyPassReverse /ws ws://127.0.0.1:5100/webpage/ws

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5100/webpage/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5100/webpage/

    <Directory />
            Require all granted
            Options -Indexes
    </Directory>

    Alias /static /path/to/my/static/folder/
    <Directory /path/to/my/static/folder/>
            # directives to effect the static directors
            Options +Indexes
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I've copied the `js` and `lib` from the `venv/Lib/site-packages/bokeh/server/static` to my static folder. However, when I try to access the site I just get a blank site and when I inspect the page I find                     `console.log("Bokeh: ERROR: Unable to run BokehJS code because BokehJS library is missing");`

(The page renders as expected when I view it locally)

Any ideas what I've might have done wrong?

Comment: Did you follow the documentation and added the needed modules? Have you restarted apache after the changes?

Comment: Thanks I missed to enable 1 of The 3 modulens (the The proxy_wstunnel) now The page loads :)

Comment: I'm glad i could help. I have posted my comment as an answer as well. Maybe you could mark it as the accepted solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the needed modules and restart apache after the changes.

```
a2enmod proxy
a2enmod proxy_http
a2enmod proxy_wstunnel
apache2ctl restart
```